# How to avoid repetition into list while building dataset

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataset, repeat

I am trying to create the following dataset:

```
multiple_newbooks = {"Books'Tiltle":["American Tabloid", 'Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed Altri amori malinconici', '1984' ],
                         'Authors':['James Ellroy', 'Daria Bignardi', 'George Orwell'],
                         'Publisher': [('Mondadori' for i in range(0,2)), 'Feltrinelli'], 
                         'Publishing Year':[1995, 2022, 1994], 
                         'Start': ['?', '?', '?'], 
                         'Finish': ['?', '?', '?']}
```

As you could some data present some repetitions. I would just avoid using the `.append` function outside the data frame I am creating for the `'Publisher' row` (***since the code you see here does not work***) or to avoid the following sequence of equal data:

```
'Start': ['?', '?', '?'], 
'Finish': ['?', '?', '?']
```

Could you possibly know how to use alternative elegant and smart code? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you convert list to set, you can avoid repetitions. set(list(["One","One","Two"])) gives ["One", "Two"]

Comment: No. I think my question has been misunderstood. I meant to avoid single writing of equal variables into the dataset. As you could see some of them are equal (there are three question marks, for example)

Comment: ['?', '?', '?'] -> ['?'] - do you need this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to repeat writing the strings. You can use for example `*` to repeat the string:

```py
multiple_newbooks = {
    "Books'Tiltle": [
        "American Tabloid",
        "Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed Altri amori malinconici",
        "1984",
    ],
    "Authors": ["James Ellroy", "Daria Bignardi", "George Orwell"],
    "Publisher": ["Mondadori"] * 2 + ["Feltrinelli"],
    "Publishing Year": [1995, 2022, 1994],
    "Start": ["?"] * 3,
    "Finish": ["?"] * 3,
}

print(multiple_newbooks)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Books'Tiltle": [
        "American Tabloid",
        "Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed Altri amori malinconici",
        "1984",
    ],
    "Authors": ["James Ellroy", "Daria Bignardi", "George Orwell"],
    "Publisher": ["Mondadori", "Mondadori", "Feltrinelli"],
    "Publishing Year": [1995, 2022, 1994],
    "Start": ["?", "?", "?"],
    "Finish": ["?", "?", "?"],
}
```

---

Or better:

```py
multiple_newbooks = {
    "Books'Tiltle": [
        "American Tabloid",
        "Libri che mi hanno rovinato la vita ed Altri amori malinconici",
        "1984",
    ],
    "Authors": ["James Ellroy", "Daria Bignardi", "George Orwell"],
    "Publisher": ["Mondadori" for _ in range(2)] + ["Feltrinelli"],
    "Publishing Year": [1995, 2022, 1994],
    "Start": ["?" for _ in range(3)],
    "Finish": ["?" for _ in range(3)],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was instructive. If you want have a look to another question I have posted here
 httpss://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056401/how-to-enter-new-rows-in-a-dataset-by-keeping-same-index/73056588#73056588 and you please to take a look and suggest something just let me know. Thanks :)